# PXException is throwing error instead of error message in the grid

Tags: acumatica

I am using PXException, however instead of showing an error message in the grid it is throwing an unhandled exception.

```
throw new PXException("Error message");
```

Error Message--

Below error I am getting--

Error:  Error #145: One or more items have not been processed.     Send
Raised At: 4/24/2015 2:38:55 PM Screen: ES.60.60.60 Command: Process
   Details: 
4/24/2015 2:38:55 PM Error: 
Error #145: One or more items have not been processed.

at PX.Data.PXProcessingBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass13`1.b__11(List`1 list) 
   at PX.Data.PXProcessing`1.Process(PXAdapter adapter) 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0) 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__c.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__c.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
throw new PXSetPropertyException("Message", PXErrorLevel.RowError);
```

Edited syntax:

```
sender.RaiseExceptionHandling("fieldName", row, null, new PXSetPropertyException("Message", PXErrorLevel.RowError))
```

After digging in Acumatica source code I found this:

```
PXProcessing<APRegister>.SetError(i, e);
```

i - index of your current processing records;
e - the exception

Comment: It still throws exception instead of showing it in the grid (little red cross at the start of row).

Comment: It is a process page with a grid in it. When I check one of the row and if something goes wrong, I want to show a error message at the beginning of the row (same as Acumatica displays in other screens)

Comment: Oh sr. I don't have my IDE here so I don't remember the correct syntax. I believe you can use [sender].RaiseExceptionHandling("fieldname", yourValue, yourRow, new PXSetPropertyException("message", PXErrorLevel.RowError)). Which is sender is your cache of your current grid you want to show the error, yourValue you can leave null, yourRow is the row you want to raise the error. I don't remember which argument comes first. Hope it'll help

Comment: The 3rd option above should do ok for a processing page. I was able to accomplish this just the other day with a slight variant of syntax. I did have to keep track of the line index though or all success/error icons ended up on the wrong line.                                                    PXProcessing.SetError(idx, PXMessages.Localize("Error Message."));
In like manner the following shows the success message                         PXProcessing.SetProcessed();

Comment: PXProcessing.SetCurrentItem(obj);
                        PXProcessing.SetProcessed();
Just a note when setting the line to "Processed" you must also set the current item.

Comment: It's easier if the process function is by-item process. Something like public static void ProcessItem(DAC item), then just simply throw exception

Comment: You might be correct. Tried with all the options but for some reason, the error does not appear at the beginning of the row. It just do not do anything, code simply executes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was my Grid was pointing to my `PXSelect<...>` data view instead of `PXProcessing<...>` data view.
I also set the following properties on the grid, (same as an existing working Processing window).
`AllowPaging = true`
`BatchUpdate = true`
`ID = grid`
`SkinID = PrimaryInquire`
`AllowSearch = True`
`NoteIndicator = True`

Works like other screens now.